# Sticky Footer with Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to have a sticky footer in conjunction with a Google Visualization which will take up the remainder of the container.  Take a look at this page:

http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/responsivedesign2.html

So in this situation, I would like to have the orange sticky footer be on the bottom, and have the map take up whatever remains.  But it appears the Google Visualization takes up the entire space and "pushes out" the sticky footer.  If you comment the **drawchart** call, the sticky footer appears on the bottom as it should.

Code (also available on [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mschenkel/2h0vvq0t/3/))

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .page-wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        /* equal to footer height */
        margin-bottom: -300px;
      }
      .page-wrap:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
      }
      .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .site-footer {
        background: orange;
      }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

      google.load('visualization', '1', {
        'packages': ['geochart'],
        'callback': drawMap
      });

      function drawMap() {
        var data;
        var chart;
        var options;

        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sessions');
        data.addRow([{v: '150', f: 'Europe'}, 527]);
        data.addRow([{v: '019', f: 'Americas'}, 518]);
        data.addRow([{v: '142', f: 'Asia'}, 336]);
        data.addRow([{v: '009', f: 'Oceania'}, 46]);
        data.addRow([{v: '002', f: 'Africa'}, 30]);
        options = {
        region: 'world',resolution:'continents'};
        chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer" class="site-footer">
      I'm the Sticky Footer.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add some attributes to your CSS styling ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h0vvq0t/6/)):

```
.page-wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            /* equal to footer height */
            margin-bottom: -300px;
            position: fixed;
        }
.site-footer {
            background: orange;
            bottom: 0; 
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
```